# What values should I put for a parameter with type the of List<? extends Map<String, ?>>?

Tags: java, android, generics

I'm trying to implement my own Adapter that extends SimpleAdapter. But one of the parameters of the `SimpleAdapter`'s constructor needs a `List<? extends Map<String, ?>>`. How can I put such values inside that parameter?

I have tried creating my own class that extends Map but as it turns out, Map is an interface and should instead be implemented. So I really haven't moved on much with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

E.g. a `List<Map<String, String>>` would be assignment compatible
with `List<? extends Map<String, ?>>`.

Any subtype of `List` is allowed.
The first `?` means that any subtype of `Map` is allowed.
The second `?` means that any value type is allowed.

So e.g. a `LinkedList<TreeMap<String, Foo>>` would also work.